# how to get sip2peer work in Android

Tags: android, p2p

I'm trying to use the `sip2peer` example from http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer, downloaded the android code, ran the example, nothing happens.

I read some questions and answers, it seems like I need to install server for this to work?

Sorry for the basic question, I'm stuck here.

I want to get the example working on my local machine and emulator

Answer (score 0):

did you download the sip2peer tutorials (s2p-Tutorial.pdf, s2p-Tutorial-Android.pdf, s2p-Tutorial-Bootstrap-FullPeer-SBC.pdf) from http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer/downloads/list?

They describe the main framework concepts and a complete example with a Full Peer implementations. The example is based on a FullPeer and a Bootstrap node that allows to discover the initial peer list. The library has been designed to build p2p networks and generally distributed systems I suggest to test it using multiple Java Nodes to better understand the approach and the architecture and then include an Android node in your network.

Given that you were talking about an Android Emulator I would like to suggest to properly check emulator network interfaces (and its addressing) since you need to be able to contact other nodes on your local machine. I always use a real device to easily manage this problem.

Regards

Comment: Do you need a server to use SIP2Peer?